# How can I shorten Laravel API response time?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, laravel-api

I was pulling the data this way, but when I query with Postman, it takes too long to get the response.

```
public function getAllItems(Request $request)
    {
        $type = $request->input('type');
        
        $query = Item::query();
        
        if ($type === 'series') {
            $query->where('is_series', true);
        } elseif ($type === 'movies') {
            $query->where('is_series', false);
        }

        $items = $query->get();
        
        return response()->json($items, 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    }
```

I tried using caching to shorten the response time. I also added the start and end times of the query to the response.

```
public function getAllItems(Request $request)
{
    $type = $request->input('type');

    $cacheKey = 'all_items_' . $type;

    $startTime = microtime(true);

    if (Cache::has($cacheKey)) {
        $items = Cache::get($cacheKey);
        
        $endTime = microtime(true);
        $executionTime = ($endTime - $startTime);
        
        return response()->json([
            'isCache' => true,
            'time' => $executionTime . ' seconds',
            'data' => $items,
            ], 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    } else {
        $query = Item::query();
        
        if ($type === 'series') {
            $query->where('is_series', true);
        } elseif ($type === 'movies') {
            $query->where('is_series', false);
        }

        $items = $query->get();

        Cache::put($cacheKey, $items, now()->addMinutes(60));
        
        $endTime = microtime(true);
        $executionTime = ($endTime - $startTime);
        
        return response()->json([
            'isCache' => false,
            'time' => $executionTime . ' seconds',
            'data' => $items,
            ], 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    }
}
```

[image: Postman response ss]

However, as you can see in the screenshot, there is a big difference between the time I added to the response and the time it took for Postman to return the response.

How can I get the response faster?

Comment: 13 secs just seems so high, Are you communicating with the server locally? if not, it could be that your internet connection is bad and 3mb took a while to download.
Also, this is a shot in the dark, but i would try         Cache::put($cacheKey, $items->toArray(), now()->addMinutes(60));
Not sure how laravel's serialization/deserialization works but i think its different when you try to cache models as opposed to using the toArray method

Comment: Laravel applications are always slower locally using `artisan serve` than in production.  Check if you can add Timers to your controller and see if you can spot the bottleneck. Also check if `is_series` uses an index in your database, it will increase query performance. As your queries will get complexer, your indexes will probably get complexer too. Based on your example there's only 1 where statement. Although that might not be the exact query based on model boot code.

Comment: @Leroy The data comes from the cache here, so this is not an SQL performance issue.

Comment: Same kind of question. How is your cache driver configured. It could be on a different network. For example your app locally and your cache somewhere in the cloud.  Add some Timers to discover your bottleneck.

Comment: @Leroy The screenshot shows that the cache retrieval takes 0.08 s.

Comment: I would measure the time it takes to execute `json_encode($items)`. How many elements are there in the array?

Comment: @Olivier There are more than 1000 items in the array. However, since it is fetching from the cache, shouldn't it still be fast?

Comment: @RafatMahmoud Dude, I think this method seems to work for me. Although it took a long time when caching at first, it took a very short time when pulling the data from the cache. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: in the else part, would the speed change if you only fetch the first 5 items instead of all? Maybe you have a ridiculous number of items being fetch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I implemented the following solution to the problem:

I added the array to the cache using the "toArray()" method.
Thus, when it fetches the data in the cache, it will not waste time parsing it again.

I save the data in the cache indefinitely and update this cache when necessary with another function.

Here's what the final version looks like:

```
public function getAllItems(Request $request)
{
    $type = $request->input('type');
    
    $cacheKey = 'all_items_' . $type;
    
    if (Cache::has($cacheKey)) {
        $items = Cache::get($cacheKey);
        
        return response()->json(['data' => $items], 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    } else {
        $query = Item::query();
        
        if ($type === 'series') {
            $query->where('is_series', true);
        } elseif ($type === 'movies') {
            $query->where('is_series', false);
        }
        
        $items = $query->get();

        Cache::forever($cacheKey, $items->toArray());

        return response()->json(['data' => $items], 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    }
}
public function updateCache(Request $request)
{
    $type = $request->input('type');
    $cacheKey = 'all_items_' . $type;
    
    $query = Item::query();

    if ($type === 'series') {
        $query->where('is_series', true);
    } elseif ($type === 'movies') {
        $query->where('is_series', false);
    }
    
    $items = $query->get();
    
    Cache::forever($cacheKey, $items->toArray());
    
    return response()->json([
            'status' => true,
            'message' => $type . ' Cache updated successfully',
            'statusCode' => 200
            ], 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, there are several ways: firstly, ignore extra columns in the query by using the `select` method, secondly, use pagination.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to reduce API response.

1. Use select method. so it will be select only the column you need.

Example:

```
$items = $query->select('id', 'name', 'description', 'created_at', 'updated_at')->get();
```

2. Use indexing for your 'is_series' column because you are using condition on this column.
3. Your Cache key may overlap. Make sure your Cache key is unique.
4. Consider pagination for large datasets

Example

```
$query->paginate(10);
```

These above points will short your response time.